# GRUB with higher resolutions - really slow

Tags: grub, grub2, boot-manager

My monitor's native resolution is 4k. However, when I run GRUB in 4k (or even at something around 720p), it is extremely slow (about 1 second lag between keyboard events and reaction on the screen).

Right now, I have set GRUB to 640x480 - which works fine. It bugs me nevertheless and I would love to understand how to make it faster. I have got a GeForce 2080 Ti and a Ryzen 9 3900 (12x3.8 GHz). So even in plain software rendering mode, there should not be such a significant delay.

I would also appreciate any suggestions on where to start looking for the issue :)

Comment: What GRUB version are you using?

Comment: Same issue on 4K, 1060ti, Ubuntu 20.04. Very slow when keys are pressed, and it does this odd "two at the time" thing. For example, you press the down cursor key and it will jump two steps down at once.

Comment: Related https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/480159 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2310219